# Can I respawn a guide in Terraria if I lost to the Wall of Flesh

Tags: terraria

I killed a Voodoo Demon and his Voodoo Doll fell into the lava and the Wall of Flesh spawned. I died fighting him; can I get another guide?

Answer (score 0):

It's written on [Wikia](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Guide) that :

> 1. The guide will not respawn until there is a suitable house in the world
> 2. Like any other NPC, the Guide won't respawn if there are any world events (like Goblin Attack) ongoing.

So if your town meet requirements and there's no event, the Guide should spawn soon.

Comment: You mean guide, right?